# how to fix error cant divide int and str, i cant fix it

Tags: python

```
print("===DIVIDING CALCULATOR===\n")

inputAngka = int(input("Insert the number : "))
inputPembagi = input("Insert the dividers : ")

if inputPembagi.isdigit:
    print("The result is",inputAngka/inputPembagi)
elif inputPembagi == 0:
    print("Can't divide a number by 0!")
else:
    print("Inputted data should be in integer!")
```

i want to make this code run
i cant divide between first input and second input

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the input function returns a string, even if you enter a number. You have to convert to an integer **or** float.

```py
number = input("Enter a number")
# Let's say I input 10. 
number = int(number) # Or float(number)
```

Now, you can divide.